# LINQ Order By Alphabets with Distinct Values

Tags: linq, list, lambda

I want to sort already sorted list in this manner.

Already Sorted List =

```
Ali-23423423423
Ali-234234
Ali-234234255
Bali-36365356
Bali-32326546456
Bali-361111
Tali1-234234
Tali2-2342342
Tali3-23424
```

I am trying to find a query so that I can sort it like this

```
Ali-12315254
Bali-23346363
Tali-242452345
Ali-2342134134
Bali-234234234
Tali-242342
```

and So On.

I made a loop for the job but it is very slow and some what problematic as-well. Is there any solution?

```
while (List1.Count+10 < List.Count) 
{ 
    i++; 
    if (List.ElementAt(i).Remove(List.ElementAt(i).IndexOf('-')) == List1.ElementAt(i + 1).Remove(List1.ElementAt(i + 1).IndexOf('-'))) 
    { 
        String Element = List.ElementAt(i); 
        List.RemoveAt(i); 
        List.Add(Element); 
        i--; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        List1.Add(List.ElementAt(i)); 
    } 
} 
List = List1;
```

is the  not so good way around I come up with

Comment: Which sorting rule you are trying to apply? I don't see `12315254` for Ali in original list. Same for `23346363` Bali. Also in original list you have `Tali1, Tali2, Tali3`. None of them in expected 'sorted' list.

Comment: This is just to give an idea.

Comment: while (List1.Count+10 < List.Count)
            {
                i++;
                if (List.ElementAt(i).Remove(List.ElementAt(i).IndexOf('-')) == List1.ElementAt(i + 1).Remove(List1.ElementAt(i + 1).IndexOf('-')))
                {
                    String Element = List.ElementAt(i);
                    List.RemoveAt(i);
                    List.Add(Element);
                    i--;
                }
                else
                {
                    List1.Add(List.ElementAt(i));
                }
            }
            List = List1;
a not so good way around I come up  with

Comment: @user1832624: Edited your answer to add your loop. But could you explain in words what you're trying to achieve? The loop is as clear as mud if it's working at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter this loop was the first thing which came to my mind, when I saw the sorted example :)

Comment: @user1832624 don't give us sample data. We need description of rule which you are trying to apply

Comment: @ALI OK, you want distinct names. What about random numbers? E.g. you have `A-1, B-2, A-3` You want only one `A` and one `B`. What numbers they should have?

Comment: I do not care about numbers at all. All I want is that If one name is in list 5 times it should only appear once and should appear again only when all other names have appeared once and so on. But all names should appear in list. The loop I devised works but in the end some times only one name is left and there it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give you unique items by name

```
var query = from s in list                        
            let name = s.Split('-')[0]
            group s by name into g
            orderby g.Key // don't sure if you need ordering
            select g.First();
```

*UPDATE* I think this code does exactly what you want - only first occurrence of every name is selected first, then second occurrences are selected, etc

```
List<string> sortedList = new List<string>();

while (list.Any())
{
    var query = list.GroupBy(s => s.Split('-')[0], (k,g) => g.First()).ToList();
    // list.RemoveAll(s => query.Contains(s));
    query.ForEach(s => list.Remove(s)); // I think this is more effective
    sortedList.AddRange(query);
}
```

Output for your sample data is:

```
Ali-23423423423 // first loop
Bali-36365356
Tali1-234234
Tali2-2342342
Tali3-23424
Ali-234234 // second loop
Bali-32326546456
Ali-234234255 // third loop
Bali-361111
```

Comment: There can be duplicate names; they just can't be bordering each other.

Comment: this is what I am looking for but I want all names. It only gives me only  the first/distinct names. I want that Same Formatting be applied again and again until all the elements are displayed